# Component event not being caught

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-events

It looks like the event is firing but the handler is not catching it. How do I go about getting this component event to be handled?

EVENT:

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" ></aura:event>
```

Registered event:

```
    <aura:registerEvent name="EnterTimeSheet" type="c:EnterTimeSheet"/>
```

Event Fire:

```
    updateTimes : function(component, event, helper) {
    var updatetimes = component.getEvent("EnterTimeSheet");
    console.log('update fired')
    updatetimes.fire();
}
```

Handler:

```
<aura:handler name = "EnterTimeSheet" event="c:EnterTimeSheet" action="{!c.updateSheet}" />
```

Handler JS:

```
updateSheet : function(component, event) {
    console.log('LETS UPDATE');
}
```

Comment: Is it a same compnent or parent child?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal The event is fired from the parent and I want the children to handle it. Can I go that way with a component event?

Comment: Yes you can go that way, if you use application events. Web standards say (Props Down and Events UP) https://jasonformat.com/props-down-events-up/ , 

Ideally i would use aura method for this : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/196870/19118

Answer (score 0):

A component event will not be caught by child components and while an application event will be caught, it's very expensive and inefficient - it really should be only used when absolutely necessary - ie communication between unconnected sibling components for example.

To communicate with a child, you can use an attribute (with or without a change handler) and for anything a bit more complex, you should use an `aura:method`.

Child component (c:child):

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:method name="updateSheet" action="{!c.updateSheet}" />
  <!--this can call the same updatesheet method you call in your question -->
```

Parent component:

```
<aura:component>
  <child aura:id="childCmp" />
```

Parent code (controller or helper):

```
component.find("childCmp").updateSheet()
//you can also call with parameters - look up dev guide for example
```