# How to tell contained component to reload data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I've been trying to understand the Lightning component event model, to see what would be the best way to do what I need to do.  I have a component that contains a component, like this:

```
<!-- parent component -->
<aura:component>
    <c:childComponent/>
</aura:component>
```

The child component contains a data table that is populated via an init().  When I do something in the parent component that changes the data displayed in the child component, what is the best way to tell the child component to refresh the data displayed by the data table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass values from parent to child component on click lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196857/pass-values-from-parent-to-child-component-on-click-lightning)

Comment: For the aura:attribute option, I think the child component would need an <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.items}" action="{!c.itemsChange}"/>, right?